# Got “External table is not in the expected format.” when reading Excel file

Tags: excel, oledb

I saw several posts talking about the same issues, but none of the solution works for me.
My clients push their Excel (.xlsx) files to a network drive and I am using a program to read the files automatically using following code snippet.
Most of the time, the operations are successful, but there is one client's files always failed with “External table is not in the expected format.”  However, if I open the file from Office 2010 in my local machine, then save it, then read it again, the operation will be successful.  The only problem is my automation process is broken. I think there must be something wrong in that client's files compare to others, I won't be able to ask that client how to create the files.  Is there any options from my side that I can try?  Thank you so much in advance!

```
enter code here
private void Loadfile(string filename)
{
    String sql = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
    String  constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
    using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
    {
        objConn.Open();  //<--Error will occur here
        OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(sql, objConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
        DataSet dsOriginal = new DataSet();
        objAdapter1.Fill(dsOriginal);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `*.xlsx` files need to be files in `Office Open XML` format. Those are `ZIP` archives mainly containing `XML` files. So try opening the client's `*.xlsx` files as `ZIP` archives using a `ZIP` software. If that fails, then the files are not in `Office Open XML` format. If it works, then open them using `Excel` and save as another name. Then do comparing content of original and re-saved `ZIP` archives. How do they differ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Axel.  However, I do not know how to open a xlsx using a zip software.  All my clients files are in .xlsx, and I have no problem open them using my code.  Only one client's files failed with the error.

Comment: Axel, thank you so much!  I actually took the xlsx file and save it to a zip file, then I am able to read the data through XML document.  I don't know what is wrong with the OLEDB approach, but I am able to do it all programmatically through XML approach, which solves my issue.